# rest-dsl dynamic route builder or must use static values?

Tags: rest, apache-camel

doing much reading first, will start a test project soon, but wondering, I would like to use properties to populate the root and sub paths on a camel route for rest route. is this possible or can this be done?
I have not seen any examples using vars, only hard static paths, just wondering if this is a limitation or constraint or is it business as usual in camel?

```
<rest path="/say"> can be <rest path="{{root_path}}"
<get uri="/hello"> can be <get uri="{{sub_path}}"
```

Comment: yes it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use Camel's property placeholders in all places in the Rest DSL and routing DSL (Java or XML) where a string value is accepted.

http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html